# ¿Cómo cambiar las string unicode en una columna pandas de objetos que deberían convertirse en int64?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unicode

Para hacer un pd.merge de dos dataframe sobre una columna `siren` necesito transformar une columna de tipo `object` a tipo `int64` pero no funciona. Entonces intenté con float pero me devuelvue

```
df_bdc['siren'] = df_bdc['siren'].astype(float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\u200e325559193'
```

Entonces intenté suprimir el string `\u200e` pero me devuelve que `can't decode bytes ...`

```
df_bdc['siren'].str.replace('\u200e','')

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape (1328494262.py, line 1)
```

Aqui esta una parte de df_bdc. El siren esta el penultimo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` y el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato por seguro. Anadi parte de la dataframe con CTRL+C desde Excel

Comment: Probaste utilizando decode?